# display dataannotation depend on other property MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

i Have a property CountryText that contain the text to show for the property country, So i need to do somehing like this:

```
[Display(Name=CountryText)]
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string CountryText { get; set; }
```

How can I do it please??

Comment: DisplayName is constant so you cann't chage when application running/ There are examples what you can do with Display in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
It's not possible to do it.

You would need a custom attribute to decorate your properties, and a custom model metada provider (usually inherited from DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider, which is the default in MVC apps). The custom provider would be neccessary to set the metadata defined in your custom attribute.

The problem is that you cannot access the model from the model metada provider. You can acces information on the types (model type, container type, attributes...) but not a concrete instance of the model, so you cannot get a property value and use it in the provider.

*Alternative*

You can however use a `Html.Label` to show the field title.

If you want to make it more "automatic" you can alwasy write a custom html helper which creates the label for you. This helper have full access to the model type and the model content, so you can still use a custom attribute, look for it on the html helper code, and use the content of the other property.

**If it was possible with metadata provider**

Your custom metadata provider should add all the neccesary [metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) for the view model property. This metadata provider could be convention based or use custom attributes to add the additional info.

These blog entries explain perfecty how to implemente custom attribute and metadata provider.

- [Diving into ASP.NET MVC 3 Model Metadata Providers](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=715)
- [Model Metadata and Validation Localization using Conventions](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/07/14/model-metadata-and-validation-localization-using-conventions.aspx)

Comment: in the custom displayName, how can i get the value of my property DisplayNameProperty??

Comment: You have to use Reflection. You have all the model available. You can find the property of your model by reflection. Something like this: Type modelType = model.GetType(); PropertyInfo prop = modelType.getProperty(...); string title = prop.GetValue(model, null).ToString(); (This is by heart. Perhaps it's not exact, but very similar to what youu need to do).

Comment: I haven't the model in my customDisplayName

Comment: No, you don't need it in your attribute, but in your custom ModelMetadataProvider. You can inherit it from DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider, as in Haack's code. When you override CreateMetadata method you can access the attribute, to get the display property name from the attribute, and then using reflection get the property value as explained. You can get the model using the model accessor parameter of the overriden method.

Comment: why i need to create custom ModelMetadataProvider, isn't enouth to create attribute?

Comment: You would need. However I have been trying to make a proof of context and the model isn't available in the model metadata provider. So, you cannot do it. If it was possible you would need the attribute, and something which understands and uses the attribute: the model metadata provider.